# Why won't os.chdir() change my current working directory?

Tags: python, working-directory

When I enter the following into my terminal shell, my current working directory won't change. I don't get any error codes.

```
import os
os.chdir('/Users/*myname*/Documents')
```

When I exit the shell and enter "pwd" in the terminal, I keep getting `/Users/*myname*`. It won't change the current working directory to `Documents`. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: It changes the working directory of the Python process, it doesn't affect the parent process and it's working directory. Call `os.getcwd()` to get the working directory for the current Python process

Comment: If you want to change the working directory for the *shell*, you need to use its `cd` builtin, not a separate Python process. The working directory is an attribute of a each process, not global state that is shared by all processes. A child *inherits* its parent's working directory, but otherwise the working directories of two processes are independent of each other.

Answer (score 3):

Every process has its own "current working directory". `os.chdir` changes the current working directory of the python process executing it:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/'
>>> os.chdir('/tmp')
>>> os.getcwd()
'/tmp'
```

Once you exit the python process and return to the shell process that spawned it. the working directory of that process won't be affected.

Answer (score 1):

You can imagine the python shell as a separate process. Once you are into that shell you are transferred into "another terminal" where you can programmatically interact with the file system using a library like `os`.
You can try listing all the files inside the current directory after changing directory to verify the change. Insert `os.listdir()` just after `os.chdir('/Users/myname/Documents')`.

However, once you exit the python shell you are back to the previous shell process where you started. There, the current working directory hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how `chdir` works.

Any command you give using `os` module works within Python context and not the terminal context.

Ex - You open a terminal in `/Users/abc` and then run a python interpreter there, you will get a working directory within that python interpreter and now if you make any changes in current path it will work but within that python context and it wont affect where your terminal was open.

Try this - after changing to a directory, make a file using `python` and you will get the file where you `chdir`.

Comment: Your second sentence is overly broad. If I use `os.remove` to delete a file, that file is gone, not restored after I exit Python.